# How to compile multiple themes in gulp-sass?

Tags: css, sass, gulp-sass, node-sass

I have tried to compile multiple themes using same files. My folder structure is as below

```
-styles
  green.scss
  red.scss
  -scss
     -control1.scss
     -control2.scss
```

I need the output of both control1 and control2 css files based on green and red themes.

```
     var gulp = require('gulp');         
     var sass = require('gulp-sass');
     var config = {
        includePaths: [
          './styles/green.scss',
          './styles/red.scss'       
        ]       
    };
     gulp.src('./styles/scss/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass(config).on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./style/css/'));
```

I am new in gulp-sass and any one please suggest is there any option available in gulp-sass or node-sass to generate multiple themes?

I need to get the output as

```
-styles
 -css
   -green.control1.css
   -green.control2.css
   -red.control1.css
   -red.control2.css
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would change the organization of your files to the setup below. I'll explain the new files next:

```
-styles
  main-green1.scss
  main-green2.scss
  main-red1.scss
  main-red2.scss  

  - colors
    - green.scss
    - red.scss
  -controls
     -control1.scss
     -control2.scss
```

As for those new `.scss` files. Each file would import a color file and a control file. For example, `main-green1.scss` would be:

```
@import 'colors/green';
@import 'controls/control1';
```

And `main-green2.scss` would be:

```
@import 'colors/green';
@import 'controls/control2';
```

As long as the variable names in `green.scss` and `red.scss` are the same you'll end up with the desired result. Here's a more detailed example:

**green.scss**

```
$color: #00cc00;
$background: #003300;
```

**red.scss**

```
$color: #e50000;
$background: #330000;
```

**control1.scss**

```
body {
  background-color: $background;
  color: $color;
}
```

**control2.scss**

```
body {
  background-color: $color;
  color: $background;
}
```

You would change your Gulp script to build the new `main-` files. The compiled files would be:

**main-green1.css**

```
body {
  background-color: #00cc00;
  color: #003300;
}
```

**main-green2.css**

```
body {
  background-color: #003300;
  color: #00cc00;
}
```

**main-red1.css**

```
body {
  background-color: #e50000;
  color: #330000;
}
```

**main-red2.css**

```
body {
  background-color: #330000;
  color: #e50000;
}
```